# Image not shown for result suggestions in SearchBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, search-box

I'm trying to use the `SearchBox` control introduced in Windows 8.1, but I can't figure out how to display the image in the result suggestions. The suggestions appear, but the space where the image should be remains blank:

[image]

Here's my XAML:

```
<SearchBox SuggestionsRequested="SearchBox_SuggestionsRequested" />
```

And my code behind:

```
    private async void SearchBox_SuggestionsRequested(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
        try
        {
            var imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///test.png");
            var imageRef = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(imageUri);
            args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection.AppendQuerySuggestion("test");
            args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection.AppendSearchSeparator("Foo Bar");
            args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection.AppendResultSuggestion("foo", "Details", "foo", imageRef, "Result");
            args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection.AppendResultSuggestion("bar", "Details", "bar", imageRef, "Result");
            args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection.AppendResultSuggestion("baz", "Details", "baz", imageRef, "Result");
        }
        finally
        {
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

---

Some extra details:

I tried to debug it with XAML Spy; each suggestion `ListViewItem` has its `Content` set to an instance of `Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.Core.SearchSuggestion`. On these `SearchSuggestion` objects, I noticed that the `Text`, `Tag`, `DetailText`, and `ImageAlternateText` properties are set to their correct value, but the `Image` property is null...

---

EDIT: So apparently `AppendResultSuggestion` accepts only an instance of `RandomAccessStreamReference`, not any other implementation of `IRandomAccessStreamReference`. I think this is a bug, since it's inconsistent with what is conveyed by the method signature. I [filed it on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807704/searchbox-windows-8-1-doesnt-show-the-image-if-it-is-not-an-instance-of-randomaccessstreamreference), please vote for it if you want it fixed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of `AppendResultSuggestion` calls for a `IRandomAccessStreamReference`:

```
public void AppendResultSuggestion(
    string text, string detailText, string tag, 
    IRandomAccessStreamReference image, 
    string imageAlternateText)
```

You can get it, if you already have a `StorageFile` (which you do) using [`CreateFromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.randomaccessstreamreference.createfromfile):

```
RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(IStorageFile file)
```

But since you are starting with a URI, you might as well skip the extra step and use [`CreateFromUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.randomaccessstreamreference.createfromuri.aspx):

```
RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(Uri uri)
```

So you'd have something like:

```
var imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///test.png");
var imageRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(imageUri);
args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection.AppendResultSuggestion("foo", "Details", "foo", imageRef, "Result")
```

Comment: Locating the cursor above `StorageFile` an pressing `F12` key, shows the declaration of `StorageFile`. Apparently `StorageFile` already implements `IRandomAccessStreamReference`, why a different method is required?

Comment: @Kiewic a very good question to which I do not have an answer. All I know is that not all implementations of `IRandomAccessStreamReference` are the same and that using `RandomAccessStreamReference` is supposed to be more "lightweight," so that's what I use (and well, it works ;) ). Maybe it should be a SO question…

Comment: It works, thanks!! I was sure it was supposed to work with `StorageFile`, since it implements `IRandomAccessStreamReference`. I had also tried to create my own implementation, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @madd0, I filed [a bug on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807704/searchbox-windows-8-1-doesnt-show-the-image-if-it-is-not-an-instance-of-randomaccessstreamreference), since the method signature implies that it should accept any implementation of the interface.